# Using .length in bookmarklet not working

Tags: jquery, firefox, bookmarklet

I'm trying to get a list of links printed to a new tab from a page, but for some reason my bookmarklet doesn't work when I'm checking `.length` in an `if` statement. I have another one that works perfectly fine, but this one just doesn't trigger.

This is my code so far

```
javascript:(function(){
    $total=0;
    $data="";
    if($("td.normal a").length > 0){
        $("td.normal a").each(function(){
            if($total>0){
                $data = $data+"<br/>";
            }
            $data = $data+$(this).attr('href');
            $total++;
        });
    } else {alert("No links found");}
    myWindow = window.open("data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(data),"_blank", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.focus();
})();
```

I've tried just doing the following and it doesn't even work

```
javascript:(function(){if($("td.normal a").length > 0){alert("Yes");}else{alert("No");}})();
```

But this does

```
javascript:(function(){alert("Yes");})();
```

The page is formatted like so

```
<table class="premium" cellspacing="2" style="margin:auto;width:600px">
    <tr>
        <td class="normal titre ohidden" style="width:500px">FileName</td>
        <td class="normal titre" style="width:100px">Size</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="normal alg" style="padding-left:10px;overflow:hidden"><a href="http://www.example.com" title="Link to file">File Name</a></td>
        <td class="normal">835.20 MB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="normal alg" style="padding-left:10px;overflow:hidden"><a href="http://www.example.com" title="Link to file">File Name</a></td>
        <td class="normal">851.20 MB</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone see what may be going wrong? I've only tested in Firefox so far.

**EDIT**

I just tried to run the code on another website and it works fine, so seems to just be the website I'm working on is somehow blocking it. I'm trying to get a list of links from 1fichier which a workmate uses to send me files in a "shared folder", and viewing a page with multiple links takes ages to import into my downloader.

The error console is spitting back `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)`

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get this to work with some basic Javascript

```
javascript:(function(){
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("td.normal>a"), i;
    if(links.length>0){
        var data="";
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            if(i>0){data = data+"<br/>";}
            data = data+links[i].href;
        }
        myWindow = window.open("data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(data),"_blank");
        myWindow.focus();
    } else {alert("No links found");}
})();
```

Still don't know why it wouldn't work, but this does.